# Django - heterogeneous query

Tags: django, inheritance, orm

Consider this model:

```
SoccerMatch(Model):
    """
    FIFA World Cup 2014 match. It could have no teams yet
    if it's scheduled but a shootout stage (they are never
    defined until both previous winner are determined)
    """
    #this is defined beforehand
    date = DateTimeField()
    #this is defined beforehand -for group matches- and when
    #the previous winners are determined -for shootout matches-
    team1 = ForeignKey(Team, related_name="+", null=True)
    team2 = ForeignKey(Team, related_name="+", null=True)
    #these are defined when the match ends
    goals1 = PositiveSmallIntegerField(null=True, blank=True)
    goals2 = PositiveSmallIntegerField(null=True, blank=True)

GroupSoccerMatch(SoccerMatch):
    """
    FIFA World Cup 2014 match for first stage.
    Each group has 4 teams and plays 6 matches.
    """
    group = ForeignKey(Group, related_name="matches")

ShootoutSoccerMatch(SoccerMatch):
    """
    FIFA World Cup 2014 match for second stage.
    Second stage plays 16 matches in rounds of
    8, 4, 2, 1 (3rd and 4th) and 1 (1st and 2nd).
    """

    #... more fields related to the shootout hierarchy
    #....those fields are omitted since they don't matter here

    #this is defined when the match ends
    penalty_shootout = PositiveSmallIntegerField(null=True, blank=True, choices=((1, "Team 1 won"), (2, "Team 2 won")))
```

In this code (where I omitted the team and group definition since it's trivial regarding involved data and trivial regarding the problem) I model soccer matched for a world cup (currently is only for this world cup) and I want to make a prediction over the matches results.

Consider the previous models have their own `clean()` methods.

This application can be configured to have exact predictions (where you must guess goals of both teams and the winner of penalty round **IF EXISTS**) or inexact predictions (where you must guess the winner in goals count or, if they tied **AND PENALTY ROUND EXISTS**, the winner of that penalty round).

In both cases, I have to consider the penalty round, which could not exist (for the first 48 matches, it does not exist at all).

My model class for the predictions was:

```
class Prediction(Model)
    user = ForeignKey(User, related_name="predictions")
    match = ForeignKey(SoccerMatch, related_name="predictions")
    goals1 = PositiveSmallIntegerField(null=True, blank=True)
    goals2 = PositiveSmallIntegerField(null=True, blank=True)
    penalty_shootout = PositiveSmallIntegerField(null=True, blank=True, choices=((1, "Team 1 won"), (2, "Team 2 won")))
```

Consider the simplest case: Exact prediction - a good prediction has goals1=match.goals1, goals2=match.goals2, penalty_shootout=match.penalty_shootout.

I thought I could resolve the accurate predictions like this:

```
#1 we consider predictions from a specific user
done_predictions = Prediction.objects.filter(user=anUser)

#2 we consider resolved predictions (i.e. involving matches played)
resolved_predictions = done_predictions.filter(match__date__lt=now() + timedelta(hours=1, minutes=30), match__goals1__isnull=False, match__goals2__isnull=False)

#3 we consider accurate predictions
accurate_predictions = resolved_predictions.filter(goals2=F('match__goals2'), goals1=F('match__goals1'))
```

Everything is fine now but I have a problem: I want to consider cases for the last 16 matches where **I must count the chance of having penalty shootout stage**.

**Q**: Is there a way I can fix the 2nd and 3rd query to consider that case instead of (making two) separate queries? (this means: cannot query `match__penalty_shootout=` since SoccerMatch ha not that field) Alternatively: Is there a way to declare a "ficticious field" `penalty_shootout` for group matched having a dummy value of None?

Answer (score 0):

Damn it. Found how to resolve it.

Django allows to traverse, by query parameter lookup, derivated properties (e.g. managers, and in django 1.7, custom transforms).

For the same of my problem, it works for my logic to determine whether the penalty_shootout is defined (1 or 2 are the only allowed values for shootout matches upon tie) or is None.

If the match is not Shootout but a group match, the Shootout fragment will not exist for that Match record. So when querying `match__shootoutsoccermatch__penalty_shootout` I will get None when the value is unspecified (i.e. no tie) or when the Shootout subclass record does not exist. So, for my example, querying `match__shootoutsoccermatch__penalty_shootout__isnull=True` and `match__goals1=F('match__goals2')` i'm specifying tie and, due to `clean()` implementations, None cannot mean anything but that the match is not Shootout.